# Using ffmpeg to send video-stream to IP on local network with UDP

Tags: ffmpeg, lan, video-streaming, latency

I have a project going on where I want to end up having one host computer (H) able to do a lot of heavy duty tasks, and one client computer (C) sending inputs to H and receiving a video-stream of what's on H's screen. No internet, only LAN.

Requirements:

1. OS: Windows 10
2. Costs: Free software only
3. Low latency
4. Minimum 720p
5. At least 30fps

For the inputs I am currently using Input Director. It works flawlessly, and the delay is not even noticable.

The video is a bit harder. I've tried OBS-streaming locally using MonaServer to forward rtmp, but the delay was at around 3seconds which just won't do. From what I've read, this delay is mostly comming from OBS itself, and the advice seems to be using ffmpeg directly.

So I tried the following:

H:
`ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920:1080 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -bufsize 65536 -f rtp udp://192.168.200.3:1935`

Seems to be doing something:

```
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv444p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 65000 vbv_delay: -1
SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 192.168.200.3
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.29.100
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
a=control:streamid=0

frame=  188 fps= 30 q=0.0 size=    1631kB time=00:00:05.80 bitrate=2304.3kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=0.936x
```

C: VLC-Media-Open Network Stream- udp://@:1935 – Does not open.

Trying the same but sending to localhost instead of IP, and opening VLC locally gives similar result. If I make the output from ffmpeg a file instead of to an UDP-connection, the file has the result I would've liked to see streamed live.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there better alternatives for this purpose?